# Is the DotA Mod receiving the same patches as DotA 2?

Tags: dota-2, dota

So Icefrog is working for Valve and releasing patches for DotA 2 which do not only include balance patches, but also more significant ones like the recent changes on the map.

Is the Warcraft 3 map being patched aswell, or was is left behind when Icefrog joined Valve for DotA 2?

Comment: If you downvote, please write a comment why so that I know what I could have done better :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last gameplay update that DotA received was 6.83c. As of now, the latest version of Dota 2 is 6.88b, which is seventeen versions ahead, five of which are major versions.

Historically, DotA had typically gotten updates within two months of Dota 2 getting it. As of now it has been over a year since the last gameplay update for DotA, so I think it is safe to assume that Icefrog has given up on trying to maintain parity. I find this especially probable because I don't believe that it is even possible to port some of the newer mechanics to the Warcraft 3 engine anyway.

However, there is a third-party group who has redone several further patches and made their own bugfixes for DotA 1, calling their fork DotA Allstars again. They're up to 6.85 right now. I'm not sure how much they will manage to port in the future, but you may be interested in that: http://d1stats.ru/